# how to use Yii ActiveRecord relations?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

How could I search like this sql

```
select user.user_id,count(distinct user.user_id,user_lesson_read.lesson_id) as counter 
FROM 
user 
inner join 
user_lesson_read 
ON (user.user_id =user_lesson_read.user_id)
GROUP BY user_lesson_read.user_id
having counter >=3
```

In ARs?
This is db structure:

```
User
--------------------
user_id     |
1           |
--------------------

LessonRead
-------------------------------------
user_id |   lesson_id   | section_id
-------------------------------------
1       |   2           |   A
-------------------------------------
1       |   2           |   B
-------------------------------------
1       |   3           |   A
-------------------------------------
1       |   4           |   A
-------------------------------------
```

The user 1 have 3 lesson records (lesson 2,3,4)
I tried some thing like

```
'userLessonRead'=>array(
            'select'=>'count(distinct t.user_id,t.lesson_id) as b',
            //'condition'=>'',
        ),
```

and i will get a CDbException, and the sql is not correct:

```
t.lesson_id) as b, // one parenthesis here
```

Any one helps? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

> In User model,

```
public function relations()
{

        return array(
                    "lessonread"  => array(self::HAS_MANY,"LessonRead","user_id")
        );
}
```

In Search(),

```
$criteria->with = array("user_lesson_read")
$criteria->group = 'user_lesson_read.user_id';
$criteria->having = 'count(distinct t.user_id,t.lesson_id) > 3';
```

> In LessonRead model,

```
public function relations()
{

        return array(
                    "user"  => array(self::BELONGS_TO,"User","user_id")
        );
}
```

Comment: thanks! seems like i misunderstood the with() function.